# Lebesgue-Stieltjes Integral (Several Variables)

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-theory, self-learning

Let $\mathcal F$ be a convex set of probability measures or distribution functions and $F, G$ be two elements in $\mathcal F$. Let $T$ be a functional on $\mathcal F$ defined as follows. Note that $h$ is ***symmetric***. $$T(F):= \int \cdots \int h(x_1, \dots, x_c) dF(x_1) \cdots dF(x_n).$$ Then how to derive the following result, please? Thank you!

> $$T[F+\lambda(G-F)] = \sum_{j=0}^c {c \choose j} \lambda^{c-j} \int \cdots \int h(x_1, \dots, x_c) \prod_{i=1}^j dF(x_i) \prod_{i=j+1}^c d[G(x_i) - F(x_i)].$$

Moreover, what is the convention for the following formula, please? Thank you!

> $$\prod_{i=1}^0dF(x_i) := ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes down to it, this is really just a multiplication problem. First,
\begin{equation*}
\prod_{i=1}^{n}dF(x_i)=dF(x_1)\dots dF(x_n)
\end{equation*}
Now,
\begin{align*}
T(F+\lambda(G-F))&=\int\!\dots\!\int h(x_1,\dots,x_c)\prod_{i=1}^{c}d(F(x_i)+\lambda(G(x_i)-F(x_i)))\\
&=\int\!\dots\!\int h(x_1,\dots,x_c)\prod_{i=1}^{c}(dF(x_i)+\lambda(dG(x_i)-dF(x_i)))
\end{align*}
Now you just want to rewrite the last part. To make typing easier, I'm going to use $f_i=dF(x_i)$, and $g_i=dG(x_i)$. So,
\begin{align*}
\prod_{i=0}^{c}(f_i+\lambda(g_i-f_i))&=(f_1+\lambda(g_1-f_1))\dots(f_c+\lambda(g_c-f_c))\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{c}\binom{c}{j}f_1\dots f_j (\lambda g_{j+1}-\lambda f_{j+1})\dots(\lambda g_{c}-\lambda f_{c})\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{c}\binom{c}{j}f_1\dots f_j \lambda^{c-j}(g_{j+1}-f_{j+1})\dots(g_{c}-f_{c})
\end{align*}
since you're "choosing" how many of the "first" ($a$ in $(a+b)$) elements you're multiplying and how many of the "second" ($b$ in $(a+b)$), but each term in the summation must be the product of $c$ terms in total. The last line is what you're looking for. Think cubic or quartic if that's easier.

P.S. I suspect that I haven't actually done anything!

Sorry, I misread the last part of your question:
\begin{equation*}
\prod_{i=1}^{0}dF(x_i)=1,
\end{equation*}
for all intents and purposes. We just skip it--it means only the $\lambda(g_i-f_i)$ terms are being multiplied. It's the same with 
\begin{equation*}
\prod_{i=c+1}^{c}(dG(x_i)-dF(x_i))=1
\end{equation*}

Comment: Where do we need the symmetry of $h$, please? Or do we need symmetry here, please?

Comment: The above holds irrespective of the symmetry of $h$. I assume this is part of a bigger result and that symmetry will come into play later on. We haven't swapped indices so far.